# Where do I translate strings?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

Where is the interface for translating strings that modules pass to `t()`, in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find it here "admin/config/regional/translate/translate"

Comment: That interface could use some SERIOUS ux help, WOW!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, my bad. It's located here: **admin/config/regional/translate/translate**

But I was confused by the interface. The search is case sensitive so that got me to start. Then it was showing "fr", which is the language to translate to, NOT the language that it is. Click the "edit" link under **Operations** to add a translation.

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable the Locale and Content Translation Module first. Otherwise there is no page at admin/config/regional/translate/translate.